# Where can I find NPC villages?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Some have reported already to have found those in the pre-release and the option to create them is ON. I've tried to create about 20 maps and been looking everywhere and haven't found one.

Where do they spawn ? Which environment (biomes) they live ? What's the best way to find it ?

Comment: Are you sure your actually running 1.8? Do you have a hunger bar and other new features? If so are you playing on a new map?

Comment: Sure I'm on 1.8 lol...

Comment: Try looking in creative mode where you can fly?

Comment: They seem very rare...honestly disappointed in the lack of adventure.

Comment: The towns are a bit boring but they're preparation for 1.9. Mines are awesome, though, and filled with track, which means rollercoasters for all.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This may not be exactly what you're looking for but you'll get to see a village at least. Try a new map with the seed `gimmeabreak` - it generates a map with a village right at the spawn point.

Oh and while you're there, dig below the well to find the abandoned mine!

[via [Minecraft reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/kalo6/start_a_new_beta_18pre_map_with_seed_gimmeabreak/)]

Comment: Since the seed led me to a village, this is the only way I could saw one :P

Comment: I concur, use the gimmeabreak seed. It's not worth the effort to try and find it by playing properly. If you already found a village in 1.8, the new villagers are a huge anticlimax anyway. You'll be glad you didn't waste more of your time (like I did).

Answer (score 2):

There was a [tweet](http://twitter.com/#!/notch/statuses/101219771936276480) from Notch on 10th August saying that, eventually, Towns will have their own biome. How common the biome is, however, will remain to be seen in future updates.

Answer (score 2):

`341414797482072298` is a seed where you spawn next to a strong hold and a village! Try it!

Comment: [But Jens said strongholds are supposed to be 500 meters from spawn...](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30340/how-can-i-find-my-worlds-strongholds/30350#30350)

Comment: @John, the way I see it, it means that it spawns WITHIN 500 meters: **...said at PAX that strongholds spawn within a 500 block radius..**

Comment: @fireDude67 Oh **within** 500 blocks!  That changes things considerably.  :)

Answer (score 1):

You can find villages by going to a place where there is no large body of water ( seas& really big lakes etc.) and they usually live on deserts or flatlands. Some signs I realized in villages is that they have a lava lake which is basically a pool of lava above ground. They tend to have sheep and pigs. The best time to locate a village is at night because a village is bright because of the torches.

P.S.

If you find a village, you might want to raid their chests if you are short on supplies

Answer (score 0):

Well the best seed I've run into is "gimmeabreak" and "Free". I won't talk about gimmeabreak because Nick already did, but to find the village in Free, you should spawn in a desert biome on top of tree near a ravine. Turn around and there's a cool village in and around a crater.

Comment: Posting seeds is not very useful because once the terrain generator is updated, it won't work anymore.