# How can I find Villages in my world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there any way you can find NPC villages in your world? Assuming the map's settings aren't set to "superflat" or "large biomes", is it more or less running off in different directions, hoping to find one? Or are there clues or hints that can lead you towards villages?

Comment: This question is not out of date at all. You can now CREATE or MOVE villages, but those options have nothing to do with finding a naturally spawned one in any length of time. The fastest way to FIND a village remains the same to my knowledge.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I find NPC villages?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30083/where-can-i-find-npc-villages)

Comment: i always find them in the desert biome

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As far as an in-game (i.e. "not cheating") solution, the only real guidance I have found is this line from the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/NPC_Village):

> They only occur in the plains or desert biomes.

So that's where you should limit your searching to, probably around the edges of the deserts as this image shows:

[image]

Another alternative listed in the ["Finding NPC Villages" section](https://minecraft.wiki/w/NPC_Village#Finding_NPC_Villages) of the wiki involves making a superflat version of your map (using your map seed), then flying around in creative mode. As noted, however, this can give you many false positives (i.e. villages that spawn on the superflat map that *wouldn't* spawn on the normal map due to the presence of a non-flat biome).

Options outside of the game, as listed in [this answer about finding strongholds](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/30350/15), would be to use cartography programs to inspect your map for tell-tale blocks that you might see in villages. Good indicators might be:

- Bookshelves or crafting tables, which show up in village libraries.
- Pressure plates, which are used to make tables in houses and shops.
- Furnaces or iron bars, which show up in village forges.
- Many rows of wheat.

Comment: also, to follow on from the above, maps are 'randomly' generated, and carry on expanding and generating more in so far as you keep walking to near an edge of your existing map. Therefore, you may well not have a village on your existing map but if you keep exploring you can be reassured that you will find one. To find it when you are exploring, follow the pointers above :)

Comment: I know the seed for the village in the pic (I know it sounds wierd but its "Biggerthanyours"

Comment: @OHAI, do you (or gnovice) happen to know the coordinates of the village?